# long press recyclerview android with context menu

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I developing app in which there is `RecyclerView`. I need to call `ContextMenu` in which will be point for delete current item in `RecyclerView`.

```
class FavoriteQuotesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {



    CardView cardView;
    TextView contentOfQuote, authorQuote;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    FavoriteQuotesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        this.contentOfQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contentOfQuote);
        this.authorQuote = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorQuote);
        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Edit");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do not understand how I will refer to the item in the menu of the current item

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FavoriteQuotesHolder holder, int position) {
    LikedQuote likedQuote = getItem(position);
    holder.contentOfQuote.setText(likedQuote.getQuote());
    holder.authorQuote.setText(likedQuote.getAuthor());
    holder.itemView.????????????
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add a context menu for every item in your recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

activity need to be registered for recycler view long click:

```
registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);
```

itemview should be long clickable:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
```

implement setOnlongClickListner on itemView:

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602856/104085

The best one is binding this functionality to custom viewholder class.